# node.js express won't open in browser

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I can open a browser page with HTML/CSS & it works, but when I type in the code for node.js then click on Go Live, the files show up but no message or any network traffic. I updated everything. I even copied & pasted the code from Node.js for the express server but it won't load to the browser. [this is all that shows up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4sl5.png)

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to share more details and provide your code

Comment: Clicking **go live** is like going to the restaurant and asking to serve you ingredients instead of the meal. You have to run javascript with node runtime to get the results you want. Just serving the files won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go live (with VSCode Live Server Extension) and running your server with Node.js are two different things.
Check Node.js getting started documentation ([Link](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/))

Comment: Thanks. I had "tunnel vision".